# Узнать принадлежит ли IP стране

Tags: геолокация, php, geoip

Здравствуйте, стоит задача, узнать принадлежит ли IP адрес Италии, может есть специальный библиотеки, которые помогут? или ресурсы, толкните куда нибуть:)

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос тут http://habrahabr.ru/qa/4592/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sypex Geo — быстрое определение города по IP](http://habrahabr.ru/post/146597/)

По мне, так самое лучше на данный момент решение, а главное, довольно шустрое, ибо гео-данные хранятся в бинарном виде. Определяет город, регион и страну. Проект развивается.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, обязательно отмечу ответ как правильный если подойдет либа.

Comment: @dogmar 
Для работы требуется всего два файла:

 - php-класс с API;

 - бинарный файл с гео-данными (7МБ) (к примеру, русскоязычный вариант в кодировке utf8 SxGeoCity.dat).
[Sypex Geo / Скачать][1]


  [1]: http://sypexgeo.net/ru/download/

Answer (score 0):

Есть специальная библиотека для PHP, называется GeoIP.

Comment: GeoIP - это PHP extensions, т.е. установка не всегда возможна (привет виртуальным хостингам).
Кроме того, бесплатная редакция базы не является полной, к примеру, отсутствуют регионы и локализация.

К тому же, Sypex Geo умеет работать с этими базами (Maxmind).

Comment: я работал с GeoIP, так она разве распознает страну? я думал она только по городам России

Comment: @dogmar В бинарном файле GeoLiteCity.dat информация о странах имеется:

[О двух способах работы геолокации (GeoIP) в PHP][1]


  [1]: http://tokarchuk.ru/2011/05/geolocation-geoip-in-php/

Мануал по GeoIP (PECL расширение):

[Geo IP Location][2]


  [2]: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.geoip.php